# Split string into an array by comma, unless comma is inside quotes

Tags: ruby

Given a string of an array in Ruby with some items in quotes that contain commas:

```
my_string.inspect
# => "\"hey, you\", 21"
```

How can I get an array of:

```
["hey, you", " 21"]
```

Comment: Likely better to use an existing CSV gem. "How" is to write a CSV parser, which is more annoying than one might suspect.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you! I looked in the Ruby CSV library and "string".parse_csv gives me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ruby standard CSV library's `.parse_csv`, does exactly this.

```
require 'csv'
"\"hey, you\", 21".parse_csv
# => ["hey, you", " 21"]
```

Comment: From what I can see, [String#parse_csv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/String.html) has been depreciated (since v1.9.2), in which case you should use [CSV::parse_line](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse_line) (i.e., `require 'csv';  CSV.parse_line("\"hey, you\", 21)`). Do you know if that's the case?.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it looks like the String #parse_csv is still alive and kicking as of Ruby 2.2.3. http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/csv/String%3Aparse_csv and http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: @CarySwoveland I couldn't get `.parse_csv` to work in Ruby 2.5.1. I really think you should have entered your `CSV.parse_line` as a separate answer, and then you'd get the credit for it that that answer deserves. Do so, and ping me back and I'll happily up vote it.

Comment: @ReggieB, did you `require 'csv'` (assuming you have a long memory). That causes `parse_csv` to be added to `String`'s instance methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using [CSV::parse_line](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse_line) or `String#parse_csv`, which `require 'csv'` adds to `String`'s instance methods) is the way to go here, but you could also do it with a regex:

```
r = /
    (?:     # Begin non-capture group
    (?<=\") # Match a double-quote in a positive lookbehined
    .+?     # Match one or more characters lazily
    (?=\")  # Match a double quote in a positive lookahead.
    )       # End non-capture group
    |       # Or
    \s\d+   # Match a whitespace character followed by one or more digits
    /x      # Extended mode

str = "\"hey, you\", 21"
str.scan(r)
  #=> ["hey, you", " 21"]
```

If you'd prefer to have `"21"` rather than `" 21"`, just remove `\s`.

Comment: I'd up vote this except it would seem to indicate that I was approving the complicated regex, whereas in fact I think `CSV.parse_line` is the best solution. I think you should split this answer in two (the regex version is interesting and may help in some conditions).

Comment: As to your first point, my view is that a code snippet--however complex--has value if it serves to help educate the reader, even if it does not represent the best way of addressing the question being asked. #2: while @steel's answer doesn't use `parse_line`, my comment on his answer should be sufficient to inform the reader of that method, which is all I care about. That comment, in my opinion, does not qualify as a separate answer.